# notebook widget - space between widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttkwidgets

I'm trying to achieve space between the notebook top panel and frame0\frame1\frame2
why when I'm using pady, like:

```
frame0.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5)
frame2.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5)
```

but there is no change.. the notebook panel and the frame stick together.. why the pady here don't impact? (for example ..I added the main_frame from the same reason to get space between the window and the notebook...to push all the notebook little down)

[image]

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk

window = tkinter.Tk()

main_frame = tkinter.ttk.Frame(window)

nb = tkinter.ttk.Notebook(main_frame)

frame0 = tkinter.ttk.Frame(nb)
frame1 = tkinter.ttk.Frame(nb)
frame2 = tkinter.ttk.Frame(nb)

lb0 = tkinter.ttk.Label(frame0, text= "Hello world")
lb1 = tkinter.ttk.Label(frame1, text= "One Two Three")
lb2 = tkinter.ttk.Label(frame2, text= "Test")

lb0.grid(row=0, column=0)
lb1.grid(row=1, column=0)
lb2.grid(row=2, column=0)

frame0.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame2.grid(row=0, column=0)

nb.add(frame0, text="tab0")
nb.add(frame1, text="tab1")
nb.add(frame2, text="tab2")

nb.grid(row=0, column=0)
main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0,pady=5)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does the notebook need to be separated or do you want to move the text down?

Comment: separated (from out side ) and move it down a little (In inner frame)..

Comment: Not sure if it would work but try adding a border width. `bd=8`

Comment: hmm.. but where ?...

Comment: Try Add it to the `nb.add` And then try add it to the `tkinter.ttk.Frame(nb)`

Comment: Example. `nb.add(frame0, text="tab0", bd=8)`

Comment: _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bd"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217274/discussion-between-connor-and-eliran-n).

Answer (score 1):

Because you are adding the frames to a notebook. The results of calling `grid` will be ignored for those frames.

The `add` method accepts a `padding` option that can have one to four values. From the official documentation:

> The padding is a list of up to four length specifications *left* *top* *right* *bottom*. If fewer than four elements are specified, bottom defaults to top, right defaults to left, and top defaults to left.

So, to add 20 pixels of padding only on the top you could do it like this:

```
nb.add(frame0, text="tab0", padding=(0, 20, 0, 0))
nb.add(frame1, text="tab1", padding=(0, 20, 0, 0))
nb.add(frame2, text="tab2", padding=(0, 20, 0, 0))
```

[image: screenshot with 20px padding]> why the pady here don't impact?

Comment: Perfect with the inner padding!
But because I'm attaching the frames to the notebook I can't separate them from the tabs ?

Comment: I just informed that I'm using Windows and when I ran the program the space that added is colored with different color from the default gray background ....little annoying ...

Comment: @eliran.n: no, you can't easily separate the frames from the tabs. That's not how notebooks work. Notebook tabs almost universally are inside the notebook rather than floating above the inner frames. If you want a completely different look for the notebook, consider reading up on how to create custom styles and custom layouts for widgets.

Comment: got it. But how can I get uniform color ? The space added by the padding=( ...) given different color - like a white frame around.

Answer (score -1):

here is the code for 1 tab. i am using a frame to add spacing.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk
from tkinter import *

window = tkinter.Tk()

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(window)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab1, text='tab1')

Frame_1 = Frame(tab1, pady=8)
Frame_1.grid(row=1,column=0)


lb0 = Label(Frame_1, text= "Hello world")
lb0.grid(row=0, column=0)


tabControl.grid(row=0, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This example doesn't add the frames to the notebook.